# Build dynamic webpage in python

Tags: python, html, sql-server

I want to create a simple webpage to display a result of a query as most of them doesnt have access to db. The output of the query is a table consisting of approx 19,000-20k tuples along with 6 attributes(query is a complex one)

The records are not static and changes on intervals.

So firstly as the no of viewer is more and also the query time is considerably large, i need to store this record at server side cache so to avoid delay everytime when one request for the page,

Secondly i need to run this query on some interval (say evey 2 hrs) to keep the page updated.

Thanks in advance for your help and suggestions.

Comment: To store this you can just use a global variable, 20K tuples should be okay memory wise. Otherwise, you should look into redis as a fast in memory database.

Comment: what framework are you using? Flask?

Comment: I didn't start the project, i was initially looking for sone suggestions.

Comment: How will it work if i store the records in a variable. Then each time do i need to execute my python script when one is requesting for the page?

Comment: I suggest you look into Flask. A very basic approach would be to use pass your variables to the HTML on the page using.